# Why is PHP changing currency symbol when I fetch data using CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am fetching data from kickstarter campaign, when I view it from my browser it displays me "Euro" symbol but when I fetch html content of the same page using CURL it shows me "dollar" symbol. Why is that so ?
 Below is my PHP code (using CURL module) :

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    return $data;
?>
```

I want it to display me correct currency symbols like if the project is in "USD" it should return me "USD" and same with "EUR".
For example below is link to a campaign which has "EUR" currency symbol but in CURL fetched data its changing to "USD" , why so ? , is PHP auto converting that based on my server settings ?
Example link : https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/35540661/new-colors-59-stainless-milanaise-loop-for-apple-w

Comment: Can we have the value of $url ?

Comment: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/35540661/new-colors-59-stainless-milanaise-loop-for-apple-w

Answer (score 0):

Your useragent is setting the location to en-us

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

I guess that is the reason the currency is set to $.

I do not know how kickstarter defines which currency to use. Maybe the server the cURL request is comming from is located in the US and kickstarter is using the ipaddress to define the currency.

Comment: I tried setting the location to en-UK , but it didn't work.
Regarding my server,  yes it is located in the US

Comment: Also I tried proxy IP's and tried to view kickstarter page from UK ip , it was still displaying "EURO" symbol there.

Comment: Could also be a cookie on your local system?